# Getting null while trying to convert and iterate XML string using java

Tags: java, xml

I'm getting null while trying to convert XML object to document for iterating the object. Please find the code.

```
String XML_DATA = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
        "<list>" +
        "<string>abd5fd81-2bd6-4479-9d60-61fe533a13b7</string>" +
        "<string>e127393b-343b-433c-87fc-27289758cca8</string>" +
        "<string>753f79fe-a1d2-4383-b5c9-3ec8aa6b7e65</string>" +
        "<string>2c71f819-65a6-4b08-8870-e71b1c770992</string>" +
        "<string>ad22d8c0-8187-4243-8189-92e94c969208</string>" +
        "<string>e6e70ab9-6149-4dfd-9d88-e27ec419847e</string>" +
        "<string>87d8566b-4c8a-4ef0-9fa9-c7b8805e5631</string>" +
        "<string>1309a729-20b4-40bb-96c8-46c96f205e60</string>" +
        "<string>5e78b822-d472-4f02-859d-de36183c5d01</string>" +
        "<string>410c70fb-8b05-47ef-bfbf-29284e45c8d3</string>" +
        "</list>";

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder;
builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
System.out.println(builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(XML_DATA))));//Displaying null
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(XML_DATA)));
System.out.println(document);
```

Comment: What does XML_DATA contain, and what is null exactly ?

Comment: @Berger updated the question with XML_DATA

Comment: And where do you get null ?

Comment: @Berger, I've printed. I've added "//" in the code. Please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your document is actually not null, `System.out.println` calls the `toString()` method of `Document`, which displays the following `String` :

```
[#document: null]
```

Anyway, you don't want to do anything with the String representation of a `Document` object.

So, just call the methods of interest and do what you want with them, for instance get the `NodeList` matching your `list` tag :

```
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("list"));
System.out.println(nodeList .getLength());
```

Comment: Berger, I've solved it. But, its returning only first tag value. Should I edit the question and post it?

Comment: You'd better post a new question, since the new problem won't match this question's title anyway.

Comment: Posted a new one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352820/iterating-only-one-xml-tag-using-java/34352876#34352876