# Iterating only one xml tag using Java

Tags: java, xml

I'm iterating an XML object, but its fetching only one XML tag value. Please check the code. It is printing only the first tag value "abd5fd81-2bd6-4479-9d60-61fe533a13b7".

```
public class sample {

/**
 * @param args
 */
private final static String XML_DATA = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
        "<list>" +
        "<string>abd5fd81-2bd6-4479-9d60-61fe533a13b7</string>" +
        "<string>e127393b-343b-433c-87fc-27289758cca8</string>" +
        "<string>753f79fe-a1d2-4383-b5c9-3ec8aa6b7e65</string>" +
        "<string>2c71f819-65a6-4b08-8870-e71b1c770992</string>" +
        "<string>ad22d8c0-8187-4243-8189-92e94c969208</string>" +
        "<string>e6e70ab9-6149-4dfd-9d88-e27ec419847e</string>" +
        "<string>87d8566b-4c8a-4ef0-9fa9-c7b8805e5631</string>" +
        "<string>1309a729-20b4-40bb-96c8-46c96f205e60</string>" +
        "<string>5e78b822-d472-4f02-859d-de36183c5d01</string>" +
        "<string>410c70fb-8b05-47ef-bfbf-29284e45c8d3</string>" +
        "</list>";

public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(XML_DATA));

    Document doc = builder.parse(is);
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("list");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
        NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("string");
        Element line = (Element) name.item(0);
        System.out.println("String: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));        
    }           
}

private static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Node child = e.getFirstChild();
    if (child instanceof org.w3c.dom.CharacterData) {
       org.w3c.dom.CharacterData cd = (org.w3c.dom.CharacterData) child;
       return cd.getData();
    }
    return "?";
}

}
```

Is there anything missing in the code?

Comment: Because you are not iterating over "string" elements ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I don't have a compiler ready right now, I do not know for sure if this is perfect. Try it and report back:

```
....
Document doc = builder.parse(is);
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("list");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
        NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("string");
        for (int x = 0; x < name.getLength(); x++) {
            Element line = (Element) name.item(x);
            System.out.println("String: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
        }      
    }
....
```

I think that should be what you are after.

Comment: No worries, glad it was helpful! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're reading just first `string`:

```
    NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("string");
    Element line = (Element) name.item(0); ### LOOP INSTEAD OF GETTING item(0)
```

To read all of them you have to loop over all nodes from `name`, similarly what you did in outer for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
    NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("string");
    for (int j = 0; j  < name.getLength(); j++) {
        Element line = (Element) name.item(j);
        System.out.println("String: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));        

    }           
}
```